# Angular routing didn't work

Tags: angularjs

I don't know why angular routing didn't work with me. I revised the code 10 times and  I couldn't find the solution. 
My index page is like -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav style="background-color:darkslateblue" role="navigation" class="nav navbar-inverse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#add">add</a></li>
                <li><a href="#edit">edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#delete">delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

      <ng-view>

      </ng-view>

        <h3 style="font-size:small" class="text-center text-info">developed by Mr-Mohammed Elwany</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Javascript page like

```js
/// <reference path="C:\Users\elwany\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\spaapplication\spaapplication\scripts/angular.js" />

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/add', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/add.html',
            controller:'addController'
        }).
        when('/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/edit.html',
            controller: 'editController'
        }).
        when('/delete', {
            templeteUrl: 'Views/delete.html',
            controller: 'deleteController'
        }).
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
    }]);

myApp.controller("addController",function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "in Add view Controller";
});
myApp.controller("editController",function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "in edit view Controller";
});
myApp.controller("deleteController",function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "in delete view Controller";
});
myApp.controller("homeController",function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "in home view Controller";
});
```

I have 4 html pages in "Views" folder their name is "add","edit","delete","home" and they have the same content.

```html
<div class="row jumbotron">
    <h2>{{message}}</h2>
</div>
```

Please I want to know why it didn't work.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: is it asp.net MVC application?

Comment: no its empty web application

Comment: @Rakeschand
i didnt get any syntax error but code didnt work

Comment: can't seem to find any issue but check out this article http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/ and also check if you are using proper versions of angular and angular route

Comment: what server are you using to test this?  `ng-route` **requires** a server because templates are fulfilled by xhr ajax requests.

Comment: local host in asp.net  and i downloaded it from nugets @Claies

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is correct but Angular applications work properly on client server architecture.

Kindly Run your application using a local server. There is no need for any Tomcat server. You can easily download a Google Chrome Plugin "Web server for Chrome". here- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/yeti/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.controller()

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {

      $routeProvider
        .when('/abc', {
          'template': "This is the ABC page"
        })

      .when('/Home', {
        'template': "This is the home page"
      })

      .when('/About', {
        'template': "This is the About page"
      })

      .when('/Contact', {
        'template': "This is the Contact page"
      })

      .when('/Service', {
        'template': "This is the Service page"
      })

    })
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Routing App</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#abc">Abc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#About">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Service">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>



</html>
```